# How to retrieve edited and checked out content sharepoint

Tags: document-library, versioning, check-out, check-in

Want to resolve an issue: with one User access  a lot of pages were checked out exclusively.the content of the pages has been modified and checked out to the USER. How to take access as a farm admin of all those content modified by user.

We want all his modification to retain without losing the content.The user is no more in org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you to publish all items, so that you can take ownership of List Item for yourself

This is the utility which will publish all items which are not published.
http://www.falchionconsulting.com/PowerShellViewer/Default.aspx?Version=SP2010&Cmdlet=Publish-SPListItems

Did you download from this area and did you follow below steps. As it working with me and I am using it from last 2 yrs

[image]

Comment: I tried to run the Publish-SPListItems and Get-SPList "http://server_name/pages" | Publish-SPListItems  but no success getting error    The term 'Publish-SPListItems' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
 name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: You have to download wsp from that website and install it then it will work. If you find helpful plz mark it as answer

Comment: Milind Thanks for your reply. I applied WSP and still getting same error.

Comment: Check my answer which is edited

Comment: I will check and revert

Comment: Now This worked at our FARM.Thanks for your effort